# What would be best approach to link css on .aspx page in .net

Tags: asp.net, css

In my .net application i have Styleshet.css in CSS folder.

Now i want to link this css in Sample.aspx.

What would be the best approach

1.

```
<link href="CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                             OR
```

2.

```
<link href="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationUrl"].ToString()%>/CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In Web.Config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ApplicationUrl" value="http://localhost/myapp/" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way in asp.net is option 3:

```
<link href="~/CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The `~/` resolves to the site path root. The difference between this and just `"css/...` is that it will work no matter what subfolder you're in. For example if your code was in

`/subsection/default.aspx`

and your styles were in folder `/css`

using a link to `"css/stylesheet.css"` would resolve (incorrectly) to `"/subsection/css/stylesheet.css"` whereas using `"~/css/stylesheet.css"` would resolve (correctly) to `"/css/stylesheet.css"`

This also differs from a hard path root `"/css/stylesheet.css"` in that it will work correctly regardless of the virtual directory configuration of the site.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Dont go for second approach as when you deploy your site to a server the `/localhost/` reference wont work.

Comment: that doesn't matter.if we deploy to server then we will change it to www.websitename.com.actually my doubt was do we need to write full path or short one is ok?

Comment: +1 @Sukhi Short one is the only good one, the other one imposes unnecessary maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Reletive path approch is much better (your first approch), Absolute paths are not portable between applications. If you move the application that the absolute path points to, the links will break.

You can find more information on below mentioned link

[Specifying Paths for Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well, always use relative paths so that you don't have to change your files after the deployment.

You can also use resolved app relative path such as

```
<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/CSS/StyleSheet.css") %> rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: There's no need escape to script to do this, you can just say `href="~/css/stylesheet.css"` as long as there's a `runat="server"` on the surrounding `head` or the `link` itself.